# Directories hierarchy for a project having a "front-end" and a "backend" side (gwt application)

Tags: gwt, code-organization

I would like to know how to correctly structure my directories for my application. I am using GWT (also GWTP) and GAE, and I have a website ("normal-mode") and its administration ("admin-mode"). So I did the following :

- src

  - com

    - mananaSeguro

      - client

        - core

          - **admin**

            - app
            - page1
            - page2
            - widget
            - etc...
          - **normal**

            - app
            - page1
            - page2
            - widget
            - etc...
          - error
          - authentication
    - resources
    - etc...
  - server

    - guice
    - handler

      - **admin**
      - **normal**
  - shared

    - action

      - **admin**
      - **normal**

Everithing is nor complete (domain name...) because I am learning GWTP and GWT and GAE in this moment. I also read about to use diferent modules, mostly because it would reduce the size of the app to download, but I did found any simple example on the web. If somebody can help me, it would be nice because, I think the project directory structure is very important. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I've build a relatively big application with GWT and I've followed the best practice from Google and i've seen that YES, it works. Normally, GWT People tell us to the MVP.

The MVP decouples your application into peices that help you to manage the whole application development.

Normally, when you use the MVP, your application will include the entrypoint which will contains:

```
public class Contacts implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    ContactsServiceAsync rpcService = GWT.create(ContactsService.class);
    HandlerManager eventBus = new HandlerManager(null);
    AppController appViewer = new AppController(rpcService, eventBus);
    appViewer.go(RootPanel.get());
  }
}
```

As you see, it creates the client-side RPC, the eventbus for notifying events, the applicationcontroller which is the root and controls everything in your application such as changing views, registering to events

The application controller also implements `ValueChangeHandler<String>` to allow it to hear when history changes and take action base on this such as changing views.
Then you'll have:

1. Models
2. Views
3. Presenters

The Model is sharable with your server. The presenter declares an interface which the views implements. Then, the presenter and the view talks through the interface and the presenter and the server talks through `rpcService` which you declared in the entry point and injected into the application controller.

Also, if you implement your application this way, you'll benefit because when you use JUNIT for testing, you can test only the presenter and therefore bypassing the view.Because if you include the view in the testing, it gonna takes lots of time. The view will declare the widgets but the presenter can import the interfaces from the view for interacting with the widget

Finally, the application hierarchy will be as follows:

--com.example.name.clients:

--AppController 
   --name.java
   --name.Service.java
   --name.ServiceAsync.java

--com.example.name.events:

--com.example.name.presenters:

--com.example.name.views:

--com.example.name.models:

--com.example.name.server:

--com.example.name.shared:

Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture) for more info,

Comment: Hi, this is not my question. I know the advantage of the MVP etc... I just want to know, how to organize my files, because I have an admin and a website, it is like 2 little applications so, how profesionals, in company are organizing a such project ? I want to know where they put their admin files etc...For example the link you gave me just give an example of an MVP application which do not use an admin side, so it is not good. But thank you for the help.